# Newton Method: min & max

Tags: real-analysis

I don't seem to find a way to prove this question; a,b two reals such as a R ; the function's class is C^2 , be
1- $f(a)<0<f(b)$
2- $f'>0 in [a,b]$
3- $f">0 in [a,b]$
a) prove the existence of m=min f'(x) and M=max f"(x) and prove that m and M are positive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question seems to be strange. $f'$ and $f''$ are continuous functions on the compact interval $[a,b]$, so they have a minimum and a maximum and since $f',f'' >0$, both of them have to be positive. For this, the first equation is not needed.